# Tasks vs ThreadPool

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have an application in C# with a list of work to do. I'm looking to do as much of that work as possible in parallel. However I need to be able to control the maximum amount of parallel tasks.

From what I understand this is possible with a ThreadPool or with Tasks. Is there an difference in which one I use? My main concern is being able to control how many threads are active at one time.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you need to control the amount of threads running? Or do simply need to control the number of ongoing pieces of work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please take a look at [ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) for `Task`s.

I would advise you to use Tasks, because they provide a higher level abstraction than the ThreadPool.

A very good read on the topic can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19222). Really, a must-have book and it's free on top of that :)

Answer (score 5):

In TPL you can use the [`WithDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383719.aspx) on a `ParallelEnumerable` or [`ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx)

There is also the [`CountdownEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx) which may be a better option if you are just using custom threads or tasks.

In the `ThreadPool`, when you use [`SetMaxThreads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx) its global for the `AppDomain` so you could potentially be limiting unrelated code unnecessarily.

> You cannot set the number of worker threads or the number of I/O completion threads to a number smaller than the number of processors in the computer.
>
> If the common language runtime is hosted, for example by Internet Information Services (IIS) or SQL Server, the host can limit or prevent changes to the thread pool size.
>
> Use caution when changing the maximum number of threads in the thread pool. While your code might benefit, the changes might have an adverse effect on code libraries you use.
>
> Setting the thread pool size too large can cause performance problems. If too many threads are executing at the same time, the task switching overhead becomes a significant factor.

I agree with the other answer that you should use TPL over the `ThreadPool` as its a better abstraction of multi-threading, but its possible to accomplish what you want in both.

Answer (score 3):

Task have a very charming feature to me, you can build chains of tasks. Which are executed on certain results of the task before. 
A feature I often use is following: Task A is running in background to do some long running work. I chain Task B after it, only executing when Task A has finished regulary and I configure it to run in the foreground, so I can easily update my controls with the result of long running Task A.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a semaphore to control how many threads can execute at a single time.  You can create a new semaphore and in the constructor, specify how many simultaneous threads are able to use that semaphore at a single time.  Since I don't know how you are going to be using the threads, this would be a good starting point.

[MSDN Article on the Semaphore class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx)